# Tesseract 3.0 with Tess4j crashing the Application on linux server

Tags: java, linux, tesseract

I am using Tess4j 3.0.0 with Tesseract 3.04 in my java Application.
In my application I've created a service for OCR which implements Runnable.

Application is deployed in Centos 6

below code is in Service.

```
Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1();
result = instance.doOCR("pathtodocument/abc.pdf");
```

I start a thread of OCR service from Document Upload Service on request from user and process the text data from PDF.

When I test the code for single request it works perfect.
Problem is : 
When I send more than one request at a time then whole application crashes.

Below is the error in catalina.out

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9514000078, pid=12979, tid=140277704374016
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_74-b02) (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.74-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f9514000078
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid12979.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
```

When I put a debugger on Service and execute the application, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you try with images and see if same type of issue occurs for images also? This seems to be issue related to Ghost4j which is used by Tess4j internally. Can you enable core dump and post more details of that dump. Post your `hs_err_pid12979.log`. If this is related to Ghost4j then you need to synchronized your processing as Ghost4j does not support multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks @sangram-jadhav . It was indeed problem with Ghost4j. 
for now I have put the Tesseract Code inside synchronized block. I will implement queue later on. I have edited the code above which is working in multithreaded environment also without crashing the application. I needed this piece of code in thread for some different reasons altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create bean for Tesseract1

```
@Bean
public Tesseract1 tesseract() {
    return new Tesseract1();
}
```

in Service : autowire Tesseract

```
@Autowire
private Tesseract1 instance;
```

put doOcr method inside synchronized block

```
syncrhonized(instance){
   String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
   //other stuff
}
```

Now Service Thread will run without crashing the application.

Note: we are loosing the concurrent OCR for simultaneous document request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you elaborate on how to create the bean which will directly have Tesseract instance inside it? Thanks