# Tess4j, Java : Tesseract causing JVM crash

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am working on integrating OCR functionality in our application. Currently whenever I run doOCr method, JVM crashes and entire application is stopped. I checked out and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832331/tesseract-3-0-with-tess4j-crashing-the-application-on-linux-server), but the answer is very unclear as it just tells to create bean, but for what, is unknown. Any ideas? Thank you.

COde :

```
 public synchronized String testOcr(String fileLocation, int attachId) {
     try {
            File imageFile = new File(fileLocation);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            String identifier = String.valueOf(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
            String blackAndWhiteImage = previewPath + identifier + ".png";
            File outputfile = new File(blackAndWhiteImage);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = BitmapImageUtil.convertToGrayscale(img, new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
            bufferedImage = Scalr.resize(bufferedImage,img.getWidth()*2,img.getHeight()*2);
 ITesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
            synchronized (instance) {
                // Point to one folder above tessdata directory, must contain training data
                instance.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/");
                // ISO 693-3 standard
                instance.setLanguage("deu");
                String result = instance.doOCR(outputfile);
                //System.out.println("Result is "+result);
                result = result.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß@\\s]", "");
                Files.delete(new File(blackAndWhiteImage).toPath());
                GroupAttachments groupAttachments = this.groupAttachmentsDAO.getAttachmenById(attachId);
                if (groupAttachments != null) {
                    saveIndexes(result, groupAttachments.getFileName(), null, groupAttachments.getGroupId(), false, attachId);
                }
                return result;
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```